# Resolving .vcxproj dependencies with c# project class doesn't return included folders

Tags: c#, visual-c++, include, project, vcproj

I'm trying to write a tool which will resolve dependencies between c++ and c# projects. 
When I try to get folders included in vcxproj, it returns everything but included folders.
I searched, where I would expect to find them:

```
ItemDefinitions -> ClCompile -> AdditionalIncludeDirectories
```

But they are not there, or anywhere else.

```
Project proj = new Project(projectFileName);

ProjectItemDefinition tp = proj.ItemDefinitions.First(pid =>
    String.Compare(pid.Key,"ClCompile", true) == 0).Value; 

ProjectMetadata tpPMD = tp.Metadata.First(pmd =>
    String.Compare(pmd.Name,"AdditionalIncludeDirectories", true) == 0);
```

Comment: Surely that's because C++ code cannot #include C# code.

Comment: It's a C# project, resolving dependencies for vcxproj file.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, C# project and C++ project have different object. If you want to get the VC++ project you should reference [VCProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcproject.aspx) and [VCProjectEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.aspx).

Here is an example about how to get the VC project you can refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.aspx